# Prevent dropping a persistent connection

Tags: java, database, postgresql, heroku

We are using Talend and rest web services to store data on Heroku. After some idle time our persistent connection gets dropped. I have search postgresql documentation but I cannot find any parameter that sets the timeout for the idle connection. Issues we are facing are following:

```
Exception in component tPostgresqlInput_2
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:281)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:403)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:283)
    at ulu.loaderherokueventsdbg_0_1.LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.tPostgresqlInput_2Process(LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.java:856)
    at ulu.loaderherokueventsdbg_0_1.LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.tJava_2Process(LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.java:617)
    at ulu.loaderherokueventsdbg_0_1.LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.tPostgresqlConnection_1Process(LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.java:1260)
    at ulu.loaderherokueventsdbg_0_1.LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.tLibraryLoad_2Process(LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.java:1114)
    at ulu.loaderherokueventsdbg_0_1.LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.runJobInTOS(LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.java:2231)
    at ulu.loaderherokueventsdbg_0_1.LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.main(LoaderHerokuEventsDBG.java:1992)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.flush(PGStream.java:518)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendSync(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1141)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:254)
    ... 9 more
```

From [this site](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Idle-session-timeout-td1880891.html) I could read that the cause for the dropped connection is probably not in the database but in the tcp layer. Do you have any suggestion how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just guessing but there can be a problem with a timeouts or idle time.
There could be other problems with network itself or your back-end responded with something that client do not understand.

I can see you are using PostgreSQL?
I am just guessing but try to comment out this line: `synchronous_standby_names = '*'` 
in `postgresql.conf` it will prevent client to wait and got time-out when waiting for a response from a server.

But as I said I just guessing here...